# Program that enters form data in a web browser

Tags: java, browser

I am trying to build a program that once a browser is opened and a login window (Let's say for Facebook) is presented, it will enter in my username and password for the site. I am familiar with the Robot class, and this could be used for the technique, however this is a messy solution. Could anyone suggest a way to go about this? Any good classes? Or is it better just to construct an add-on for a browser?

Comment: Google Chrome basically already does this. If you want this feature for personal use, maybe just use that. But if you still want to program this bot, it can give you some ideas.

Comment: I guess the next question is how do I learn to create bots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plugin gives you direct access to a browser's API so it would be the best approach.  That's how [Roboform](http://www.roboform.com/) does it,  you may want to take at look at what they did.